# Jenkins Declarative: Trigger another pipeline and pass the stage results to current pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have two declarative pipelines in Jenkins. I would like to trigger pipelineB within parameters from the stage that is running inside pipeline A and check the build/stage results of pipelineB to decide whether if pipelineA should be continue or aborted. 
If pipelineB build/stage results is success then pipelineA should continue with Stage C, unless it should be aborted.

```
       stage('A'){
            steps{
                script{
                     //Do something
        }  


        stage ('B'){
            steps {
                script {
                        // Trigger another pipeline and check result of this
                        build job: 'pipelineB', parameters: [
                        string(name: 'param1', value: "value1")
                      ]
                }
            }
        }


        stage('C'){
            steps{
                script{
                   //Do something
        }
```

Comment: What you are trying to achieve needs to be split into 2 separate workflows.

Comment: we have several microservices.. We would like to run selenium tests when we deploy rest of microservices meanwhile with UI.. Selenium just runs when we deploy uı microservices

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the downstream job build result and assign to upstream job build result.

```
script {
  // Trigger another pipeline and check result of this
  ret = build(job: 'pipelineB', 
                  parameters: [
                      string(name: 'param1', value: "value1")
                  ],
                  propagate: true,
                  wait: true)

  echo ret.result
  currentBuild.result = ret.result
}
```

Read [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/) for detail

Comment: The defaults for `propagate` and `wait` are already `true`, shouldn't his stage fail if downstream job fails without a need to do anything?

Comment: @yong, how can we add a branch_name that we would like to trigger ?

Comment: how about add one more param in pipelineB to accept branch and in the first stage of pipelineB run sh "git checkout ${params.BRANCH}" to switch to you desired branch.  Then pass down the value for the BRANCH param in above code snippet.